# Simple password based file decryption/encryption compatible with command line program?

Tags: saving, encryption

**What works currently:** With emacs25 (as comes with ubuntu 18) I use `ccrypt` on the command line to selectively en/decrypt a few specific text files. There is a package `elpa-ps-ccrypt` which, on encountering such a file, asks for the password, decrypts and lets me edit the file. On save, it encrypts it.

**What's wrong:** The package elpa-ps-ccrypt does not work with emacs28 (ubuntu snapshot package) for quite some time. It can decrypt, but when saving I get a lengthy error-message.

**What I would like:** I guess I should switch. But what is a decent successor?

**Musings:** `erc-crypt` and `kaesar` mention "openssl", which makes me cringe. But maybe that is what is the right thing to do? Or is it easier to define a save and a load action to transform files on writing and reading? How would that be done with asking the password?

Comment: Why don't you report a bug with this package? Chances are its maintainer never tested it with the snapshot.

Comment: Maybe [GNU Privacy Guard](https://gnupg.org/)? There is support for it in emacs through `epa.el`. Here is a [short intro](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2011/02/keeping-your-secrets-secret.html).

Answer (score 1):

On [ccrypt.sourceforge.net](http://ccrypt.sourceforge.net/) I found version 1.11 of ccrypt which comes with a `ps-ccrypt.el` that works with emacs 28.0.50. It is easy enough to activate that file:

1. Put the file into `.../whateverdir`.
2. If `whateverdir` is not listed in variable `load-path`, add it in one of your emacs startup files like `(add-to-list 'load-path ".../whateverdir")`
3. In that same startup file add `(require 'ps-ccrypt)`.

Now it works again.
(Disclaimer: I shyed away from sourceforge at the time of writing the questing because, well, its sourceforge :-( and the page takes ages to load).